# How to toggle the macbook menu bar battery/wifi icon on/off via the command line

Tags: mac, menu-bar

I know I can go into system preferences and for network and battery toggle the display of the icon on and off there. But I am looking for a way to do this from the command line. For example I have a monitoring script running that knows if I am using battery or not. I'd love to toggle the battery icon off when connected via AC power and back on when using battery power.

Any ideas?

Comment: The monitoring script won't be looking for the presence of a menu bar icon...

Comment: I know the script won't look for the presence of the icon. I just need a way to turn the icon of/off via command line somehow. Maybe edit the plist that controls the display of it or something.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the showing of the **Wi-Fi** and **Battery Status** icons on the **Menu Bar** from the *command line* in **Terminal**, one can use a *shell script* to do so, as in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* used as a **shell script**, presented below.

The core parts of the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor**, and the entire *script* as a *executable shell script* in **Terminal**, under **macOS Catalina** and with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup> <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>
- <sub>The *example* **AppleScript** *code* presented herein works as tested in **macOS Catalina**, however, will need to be modified for use in **macOS Big Sur** or later.</sub>

**General Notes:**

In **macOS Catalina** when the **Menu Extras** that show on the **Menu Bar** are showing, it's the **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist** *file* that contains an entry under the **menuExtras** *key* for those that show. If they are not showing, then the entry is removed from the target **.plist** *file*.

While one can use the `defaults` *command line utility*, or the `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` *command line utility* to modify the target **.plist** *file*, nonetheless, even after killing the `SystemUIServer` *process*, it does not reflect the current state of the modified target **.plist** *file*. As such, one can use **AppleScript** with **UI Scripting** and **System Events** to modify **System Preferences** to remove the target **Menu Extras** from the **Menu Bar**. To show them, it's not as complicated as removing them and it's just a matter of opening the target **Menu Extras**.

The **Menu Extras** are located at: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/`

Below you'll find two separate **AppleScript** *scripts* that will toggle the state of the **Wi-Fi** and **Battery Status** icons shown on the **Menu Bar**. They will be available for use from **Terminal**, or other methods of calling a *command line utility*.

**System Preferences** will not show its **UI**, however, its **Dock** icon will bounce briefly one time when removing the target icons from the **menu bar**. (It's barely noticeable.)

- Note that after creating and testing the *executable shell script* for each, they should be moved to a *directory* that is included in the `PATH` passed to the *shell* so they can be used by just typing their *name* without the leading `./`, or their *fully qualified pathname*.

---

### Wi-Fi Menu Bar Icon

To use the *example* **AppleScript** *code* as an *executable shell script* in **Terminal**, run the following *compound command* in **Terminal**:

```
f='wifimbi'; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

In the opened **wifimbi** *document*, copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code* into it, then save and close it.

Back in **Terminal**, type `./wifimbi` and then press enter:

It should output:

```
Missing argument, e.g.,: wifimbi [on|off]
```

Meaning to use it you type either `wifimbi on` or `wifimbi off` to add to remove the **Wi-Fi** icon from the **menu bar**.

Then test it using `./wifimbi on` and `./wifimbi off`, however, do not run the *commands* immediately back to back as it takes a few moments for the *script* to run and the target **.plist** *file* to update.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv
    
    if argv is equal to {} then ¬
        return "Missing argument, e.g.,: " & ¬
            name of me & " [on|off]"
    
    set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        the POSIX path of ¬
            (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
        "com.apple.systemuiserver.plist"
    
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
            set menuExtrasListAsString to the value of ¬
                the property list item ¬
                    "menuExtras" as string
    
    if argv is {"on"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString does not contain "Airport" then
        do shell script ¬
            "open -g '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Airport.menu'"
        return "The Wi-Fi menu bar icon is now showing..."
    else if argv is {"on"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString contains "Airport" then
        return "The Wi-Fi menu bar icon is already showing..."
    else if argv is {"off"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString contains "Airport" then
        my toggleMenuExtras()
        return "The Wi-Fi menu bar icon is no longer showing..."
    else if argv is {"off"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString does not contain "Airport" then
        return "The Wi-Fi menu bar icon is already not showing..."
    end if
    
end run


--  ## Handler ##

on toggleMenuExtras()
    
    --  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
    --  # running and if yes, then close it.
    --  # 
    --  # This is done so the script will not fail 
    --  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
    --  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
    --  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
    --  #
    --  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
    --  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.
    
    if running of application "System Preferences" then
        try
            tell application "System Preferences" to quit
        on error
            do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
        end try
        delay 0.1
    end if
    
    --  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
    --  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
    --  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.
    
    repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    --  # Open System Preferences to the Network pane. 
    
    tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
        reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.network"
    
    
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            
            --  # Wait for the target UI element to be available.
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists scroll area 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            --  # Select Wi-Fi from the list of services.
            
            try
                select ¬
                    (rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 ¬
                        whose value of static text 1 ¬
                        starts with "Wi-Fi")
            end try
            
            --  # Wait for the target UI element to be available.
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists group 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            
            --  # Toggle the state of the checkbox:
            --  # Show Wi-Fi status in menu bar
            
            click checkbox 1 of group 1
            
        end tell
    end tell
    
    delay 0.2
    
    quit application "System Preferences"
    
end toggleMenuExtras
```

**Notes:**

Using the `open` *command* with the target **Menu Extras** adds its icon to the **menu bar** and is faster than calling the `toggleMenuExtras()` *handler*.

---

### Battery Status Menu Bar Icon

To use the *example* **AppleScript** *code* as an *executable shell script* in **Terminal**, run the following *compound command* in **Terminal**:

```
f='batterymbi'; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

In the opened **batterymbi** *document*, copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code* into it, then save and close it.

Back in **Terminal**, type `./batterymbi` and then press enter:

It should output:

```
Missing argument, e.g.,: batterymbi [on|off]
```

Meaning to use it you type either `batterymbi on` or `batterymbi off` to add to remove the **Wi-Fi** icon from the **menu bar**.

Then test it using `./batterymbi on` and `./batterymbi off`, however, do not run the *commands* immediately back to back as it takes a few moments for the *script* to run and the target **.plist** *file* to update.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv
    
    if argv is equal to {} then ¬
        return "Missing argument, e.g.,: " & ¬
            name of me & " [on|off]"
    
    set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        the POSIX path of ¬
            (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
        "com.apple.systemuiserver.plist"
    
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
            set menuExtrasListAsString to the value of ¬
                the property list item ¬
                    "menuExtras" as string
    
    if argv is {"on"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString does not contain "Battery" then
        do shell script ¬
            "open -g '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Battery.menu'"
        return "The battery status menu bar icon is now showing..."
    else if argv is {"on"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString contains "Battery" then
        return "The battery status menu bar icon is already showing..."
    else if argv is {"off"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString contains "Battery" then
        my toggleMenuExtras()
        return "The battery status menu bar icon is no longer showing..."
    else if argv is {"off"} and ¬
        menuExtrasListAsString does not contain "Battery" then
        return "The battery status menu bar icon is already not showing..."
    end if
    
end run


--  ## Handler ##

on toggleMenuExtras()

    --  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
    --  # running and if yes, then close it.
    --  # 
    --  # This is done so the script will not fail 
    --  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
    --  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
    --  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
    --  #
    --  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
    --  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.
    
    if running of application "System Preferences" then
        try
            tell application "System Preferences" to quit
        on error
            do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
        end try
        delay 0.1
    end if
    
    --  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
    --  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
    --  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.
    
    repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    --  # Open System Preferences to the Energy Saver pane. 
    
    tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
        reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.energysaver"
    
    
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
            
            --  # Wait for the target UI element to be available.
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists checkbox 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
                        
            --  # Toggle the state of the checkbox:
            --  # Show battery status in menu bar
            
            click checkbox 1
            
        end tell
    end tell
    
    delay 0.2
    
    quit application "System Preferences"
    
end toggleMenuExtras
```

**Notes:**

Using the `open` *command* with the target **Menu Extras** adds its icon to the **menu bar** and is faster than calling the `toggleMenuExtras()` *handler*.

Also, with the **Menu Extras** for the **Battery Status**, there was issues with getting the **[√]** to stick when using the `toggleMenuExtras()` *handler*. While it did check it, it would only stick if the **UI** of **System Preferences** was made visible, which of course would somewhat defeat the purpose of doing this from the *command line*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Wow, just wow!!! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to remove menu bar items programmatically. (I think you can *add* them by opening the corresponding `.menu` files that are tucked away somewhere in the file system.

I can offer you a possible work-around for the battery at least:

[SlimBatteryMonitor](https://www.orange-carb.org/SBM/) is a free app that can show a different icon when on battery or charging, and can show *none* when charged. (It does still leave a tiny blank icon in the menu bar area.)

If no one else comes up with an idea, at least that's *something* to get you started.